# Why is $elemMatch return the first document, instead of the all matches documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to execute a query that returns all the documents that match based on query parameters.

I have the following schema:

```
_id: ObjectId('631b875491b16c38eecfa4e9')
brandName: "Nick"
categories: Array
products: Array
 0: Object
   productName: "Vans Shoes dsds Old Skool"
   description: "amazing Shoes."
   categoryId: ObjectId('62f3eaff3ded19dcce71081e')
   price: 240
   numberOfBuyers: 0
  _id: ObjectId(631b875491b16c38eecfa4ec)
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
__v: 0
```

The following query should give me all the documents that match, but it returns only the first document:

```
  const products = await Brand.find(
    {
      _id: brandId
    },
    {
      products: {
        $elemMatch: {
          categoryId: categoryId,
          price: {
            $gte: minPrice,
            $lte: maxPrice
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are querying on "Brand" documents. This means your query tells Mongoose: if one of the products is matching (categoryId and price), return the (whole) Brand document.

In order to retrieve only specific elements of this array, you should include your `$elemMatch` object in the projection step of your `find` call:

```
  const products = await Brand.find({
    _id: brandId 
    }, {
      //include other properties you want to include in your output document
      products: {
        $elemMatch: {
          categoryId: "62f3eaff3ded19dcce71081e",
          price: 240
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

**Update after comment**
Your products array will only contain the **first** element that was matched. This is intended behaviour (as described here: cs/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/):

> Definition
> $elemMatch
> The
> $elemMatch
> operator limits the contents of an  field from the query results to contain only the first element matching the
> $elemMatch
> condition.

In order to get several results you should probably use an aggregation pipeline using `$unwind` and `$group`.

Comment: Can you update the question accordingly? Did you use operators like`$gt`?